# Quasar x Ag-grid Vuejs2

Tags: vuejs2, ag-grid, quasar

I'm trying to use the ag-grid library, but I'm encountering the following error:

DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

To solve it, i need add the following to Webpack config:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js'
  }
}
```